# Cloud Linux with OpenGL acceleration?

Tags: linux, cloud-computing, x11, graphics-processing-unit, opengl

We are thinking about launching some Linux server-side services which would greatly benefit of having real accelerated OpenGL available. Currently we are running normal server instances with Mesa library and software rendering on CPUs. Works, albeit very slowly.

Are there any "OpenGL clouds" available anywhere? We'd rather take a solution where the server has already has working headless X11 and OpenGL in place.

I am especially looking for OpenGL + Linux as a service, I am less interested in OpenCL, CUDA, scientific calculating or rendering clusteres. It's more like "OpenGL on demand",

Answer (score 1):

You may look into "rendering farms" and specialized in 3D "clouds" like http://www.revuprender.com/

Found the info on http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/information-technology/computer-networking/TCH_ITS_CNW/582293-876677